# Event when video is done - Possible?

Tags: php, flash, html, video

Is it possible to have a flash/html5 video on a webpage, and when the video is done, it will run a PHP script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to do a check inside both the html5 player and the flash player to determine if the video has stopped playing and then you should be able to call a php script through several ways. Let's say you have a php file called 'test.php' then in html5 you'd do the following:

```
<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    video.onended = function(e) {
                $.post(
                    "test.php", 
                    function(data) {
                        /*Do stuff here!*/
                    }, 
                   "json"
                );
    }
</script>
```

In flash it's a bit different and you could try doing something like the following in actionscript3:

```
stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, statusChanged);

function statusChanged(stats:NetStatusEvent) {
    if (stats.info.code == 'NetStream.Play.Stop') {
        // create a new loadvars variable
        var lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
        lv.load("http://www.myurl.com/test.php");
        // now define what you want to do with the loaded data:
        lv.onLoad = function(){
           /*Do stuff here!*/
        }; 
    }
}
```